# Parse HTTP Response

Tags: apex, rest, string, split, paypal

How to parse the HTTP Response if response string is in name value pair.

> RESULT=0&PNREF=EFHP0D426A53&RESPMSG=APPROVED&AUTHCODE=25TEST&AVSADDR=Y&AVSZIP=N&CVV2MATCH=Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to parse it, but probably the simplest is to use `String.split`. Something like the following should get you started.

```
Map<String, String> payload = new Map<String, String>();
for (String pair : response.getBody().split('&'))
{
    List<String> data = pair.split('=', 2);
    String key = data[0], value = (data.size() > 1) ? data[1] : null;
    payload.put(key, value);
}
```